# Established results on the convergence rate of iterates for Accelerated Gradient Descent?

Tags: convex-optimization, gradient-descent

As the title suggests, I am wondering whether there exists results on the convergence rate of iterates (not the function value) for the family of Nesterov's accelerated gradient algorithms for smooth convex function?

I am aware [this paper](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01060130v3) shows the iterates of FISTA weakly converges but does not provide convergence rate.

Comment: Look at the bibliography of [this paper](http://cvxr.com/tfocs/paper/).

Comment: @MichaelGrant: Could you be a little more specific? Most of the papers listed look familiar to me. But I could not recall any of them deal with this problem.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot. If I could I'd post an answer!